# estimating deviations from ideal gas behaviour

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

How can one estimate the pressure at which argon atoms show deviations from ideal gas behaviour due to the finite size of the atoms?

I have tried Taylor expanding the hard sphere gas equation: 
$$P'(V-b)=NkT $$
to get $P'=P(1+b/V)$ to first order, where $P$ is the ideal gas pressure. However, I don't know if this is the right approach or just what to do next really. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch4/deviation5.html

Comment: It is the pressure at which b/V is on the order of about 0.05.  And the N shouldn't be in the equation.  V is the molar volume, and b is based on molar volume.

Answer (score 0):

The result is problematic that the compressibility factor is greater than 1.

The well-known Van der Waals equation is, $$(P+\frac {n^2a}{V^2})(V-nb)=nRT$$

And ideal gas EOS is, $$P_{ideal}V=nRT$$

where n is molar number and R is universal gas constant. You can use particle number if you prefer that way.

From VDW equation, we get $$ P+\frac {n^2a}{V^2}=\frac{nRT}{V(1-\frac {nb}V)}=\frac {P_{ideal}}{1-\frac {nb}{V}}$$

Using Taylor expansion and taking the first order,$$ P+\frac {n^2a}{V^2} \approx P_{ideal}(1+\frac {nb}{V})$$

Therefore, we get $$ P \approx P_{ideal}(1+\frac {nb}{V})-\frac {n^2a}{V^2}$$

Because, $$\frac nV =\frac {P_{ideal}}{RT}$$

We get, $$ P \approx P_{ideal}(1+\frac {n}{V}(b-\frac {a}{RT}))$$
or $$ P \approx P_{ideal}(1+\frac {P_{ideal}}{RT}(b-\frac {a}{RT}))$$

For argon at 15 degrees C and 1.013bar, this gives compressibility 0.99899. Though it is higher than reference 0.99925, it is less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

For a bit more empirical approach, try the compressibility factor.  With this factor, the ideal gas equation becomes PV = znRT, where z is described in very great detail by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility_factor.

For places on the "z plot" that differ substantially from a value of z=1, you will find that argon starts behaving more and more non-ideally.  This typically occurs at a high value of reduced pressure, with a low value of reduced temperature, where reduced pressure is P/Pc and reduced temperature is T/Tc (subscript c represents critical pressure and temperature respectively).